# Duplicate values multi array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

As the title states I'm searching for a unique solution in multi arrays. PHP is not my world so I can't make up a good and fast solution.
I basically get this from the database: http://pastebin.com/vYhFCuYw .

I want to check on the 'id' key, and if the array contains a duplicate 'id', then the 'aantal' should be added to each other.

So basically the output has to be this: http://pastebin.com/0TXRrwLs .

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
As asked, attempt 1 out of many:

```
function checkDuplicates($array) {
    $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $k) {
        foreach ($array as $v) {
            $t_id = $k['id'];
            $t_naam = $k['naam'];
            $t_percentage = $k['percentage'];
            $t_aantal = $k['aantal'];
            if ($k['id'] == $v['id']) {
                $t_aantal += $k['aantal'];
                array_push($temp, array(
                        'id' => $t_id,
                        'naam' => $t_naam,
                        'percentage' => $t_percentage,
                        'aantal' => $t_aantal,
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Comment: I've tried several things including looping through the array. If you want to see what exactly I did, I can't say anymore. Seen so many solutions/workarounds what didn't work the past 2 hours I can't remake them.

Comment: show us what you have tried so we can take a look at your attempts, resolve and possibly offer suggestions and alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code, each 'aantal' has initial value of 1, and duplicated id have their aantal incremented mutually, and duplicated id's are not suppressed. As your first array index is 0-based numeric, so we don't consider this dimension as a hash array, but rather a normal array.

#### UPDATED: id's can be duplicated 2 times, 3 times, 4 times, ...

```
<?php
//
// duplicate elements are not suppressed:
//
function checkDuplicates($xarr) {
  //
  $xarrDone = array();
  //
  $n = count($xarr);
  //
  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
  {
    if(! isset($xarrDone[$i]))
    {
      $id0 = $xarr[$i]['id'];
      $hasId0 = array();
      for($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++)
      {
        if($xarr[$j]['id'] == $id0)
        {
          $hasId0[] = $j;
        }
      }

      $n1 = count($hasId0);
      if($n1 > 0)
      {
        $xarr[$i]['aantal'] += $n1;
        $xarrDone[$i] = true;
        for($j = 0; $j < $n1; $j++)
        {
          $xarr[$hasId0[$j]]['aantal'] += $n1;
          $xarrDone[$hasId0[$j]] = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //
  return $xarr;
}

//
// duplicate elements are suppressed:
//
function checkDuplicates2Unique($xarr) {
  //
  $xarrDone = array();
  $xarrNew = array();
  //
  $n = count($xarr);
  //
  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
  {
    if(! isset($xarrDone[$i]))
    {
      $id0 = $xarr[$i]['id'];
      $hasId0 = array();
      for($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++)
      {
        if($xarr[$j]['id'] == $id0)
        {
          $hasId0[] = $j;
        }
      }

      $n1 = count($hasId0);
      if($n1 > 0)
      {
        $xarr[$i]['aantal'] += $n1;
        for($j = 0; $j < $n1; $j++)
        {
          $xarrDone[$hasId0[$j]] = true;
        }
      }
      $xarrNew[] = $xarr[$i];
      $xarrDone[$i] = true;
    }
  }
  //
  return $xarrNew;
}

//
// main test:
//
$xarr0 = array(
    array(
      'id' => 6
    , 'naam' => 'Aardmonnik'
    , 'percentage' => '8,00%'
    , 'aantal' => 1
  )
  , array(
      'id' => 34
    , 'naam' => 'Achel 8 Bruin'
    , 'percentage' => '8,00%'
    , 'aantal' => 1
  )
  , array(
      'id' => 34
    , 'naam' => 'Achel ppBruin'
    , 'percentage' => '9,00%'
    , 'aantal' => 1
  )
  , array(
      'id' => 34
    , 'naam' => 'Achel ppBruin'
    , 'percentage' => '9,00%'
    , 'aantal' => 1
  )
  , array(
      'id' => 3
    , 'naam' => 'IV Saison'
    , 'percentage' => '6,5%'
    , 'aantal' => 1
  )
  , array(
      'id' => 34
    , 'naam' => '3 SchtÃ©ng'
    , 'percentage' => '6,00%'
    , 'aantal' => 1
  )
);
//
echo "<pre>
Original:
";
print_r($xarr0);
//
echo "</pre>";
//
$xarr = checkDuplicates($xarr0);
//
echo "<pre>
Modified:
";
print_r($xarr);
//
$xarr = checkDuplicates2Unique($xarr0);
//
echo "<pre>
Modified Unique:
";
print_r($xarr);
//
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

?

1. checkDuplicates(): keep duplicated id's.
2. checkDuplicates2Unique(): delete duplicated id's to get unique id's.

Comment: Your "checkDuplicates2Unique" method works perfect, exactly what I wanted and needed. This was the output: http://pastebin.com/Pu3QYM8s .
Thanks! I'm going to review the solution so I can learn from it for future use!

Answer (score 1):

Try using php's array_unique function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php
It should work on arrays

Otherwise (if you can sort the array -> faster):

```
<?php

$db = array(....); // your data

function remove_duplicates (array $arr) {
  usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] < $b['id'];
  });
  $result = array();
  $last_id = null;
  $last_index = -1;
  for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); ++$i) {
    if ($arr[$i]['id'] == $last_id) { 
      result[$last_index]['aantai'] += 1;
      continue; 
    }
    $last_id = $arr[$i]['id'];
    $last_index = count($result);
    $result[] = $arr[$i];
  }
  return $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: This actually removes the duplicates but doesnt count +1 on every duplicate on the 'aantal' key. That's the main problem I'm getting...

Comment: I already did the same when I tried your solution but then the outcome is not exactly what is expected. This is what I got from my edit and your edit (which is the same I did): http://pastebin.com/9mbgABWZ .

Comment: ah right, obviously, you don't have to save `$i` in `$last_value`, you have to save the last index of `$result` aka `$last_value = count($result)` instead of `$last_value = $i`. check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Only loop over the input once, then copy the element when the id is new, else add the value:

```
function checkDuplicates($array) {
    $temp = array();
    // Only loop through the input once
    foreach($array as $k) {
        // Use the id as array index
        if (array_key_exists($k['id'], $temp) {
            // Only check id and add aantal?
            $temp[$k['id']['aantal'] += $k['aantal'];
        } else {
            // Copy the element to the output
            $temp[$k['id']] = $k;
        }
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Depending on your further code, you might need to reset the array indices by `sort()` or something.

Edit: sorry I forgot an index to $temp - the aantal field schould be correct now.

Comment: Same problem as tak3r, errors and not the actual count (aantal) that get's updated: http://pastebin.com/Jv3cugch .